# Android: "Expected resource of type menu" error

Tags: android, xml, layout-inflater

I am encountering the error "Expected resource of type menu" with this line of code

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_apps, menu);
    }
```

However my xml file actvity_apps.xml contains the menu tag and nothing else

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_configure_locale"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_configure_locale" />

</menu>
```

Can someone explain what is going on and how to fix the error?

Comment: add it inside menu folder and call it as R.menu.menuItems

Comment: yes thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain what is going on

You put a menu resource in `res/layout/`, and the build tools will not accept that.

> and how to fix the error?

Move the file from `res/layout/` to `res/menu/`. You may need to create the `res/menu/` directory.